# `pod update` command doesn't update the installed pod

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I'm using CocoaPods version `0.39.0` and I have 'TwitterKit' pod version `1.12.0` installed.

My `Podfile` doesn't specify any version for this pod...

```
pod 'ReactiveCocoa', '~> 2.5'
pod 'Fabric'
pod 'TwitterKit'
pod 'TwitterCore'
pod 'Mantle', '~> 2.0'
pod 'MTLManagedObjectAdapter', '~> 1.0.0.1'
pod 'NPReachability', '~> 0.2.0'
```

Now I want to update it to version `1.13.1` so I run `pod update 'TwitterKit'`. But it still says `Using TwitterKit (1.12.0)`.

`pod search TwitterKit` tells me version `1.13.1` is available.

```
-> TwitterKit (1.13.1)
   Increase user engagement and app growth.
   pod 'TwitterKit', '~> 1.13.1'
   - Homepage: https://fabric.io/kits/ios/twitterkit
   - Source:
   https://kit-downloads.fabric.io/ios/com.twitter.sdk.ios/1.13.1/com.twitter.sdk.ios-default.zip
   - Versions: 1.13.1, 1.13.0, 1.12.1, 1.12.0, 1.11.4, 1.11.3, 1.11.2, 1.11.1,
   1.11.0, 1.10.1, 1.10.0, 1.9.0, 1.8.1 [master repo]
```

Did I do something wrong???

Comment: Did you try to run `pod update` without naming TwitterKit? TwitterKit depends on TwitterCore which is also in your Podfile and possibly not updated when running `pod update 'TwitterKit'`

Answer (score 2):

It turns out it is a dependency issue. I have to do `pod update 'TwitterCore'` first, then do `pod update 'TwitterKit'` in order to update `TwitterKit`'s version.

For the curious ones, here is the [TwitterKit.podspec.json](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/TwitterKit/1.13.1/TwitterKit.podspec.json) :)

Answer (score 1):

updating one by one starting from TwitterCore didn't work for me. Solution was: comment Twitter pods in Podfile -> run `pod install` to remove those pods -> uncomment Twitter pods and run `pod install` again